# Find words and delete in search string

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have a list (All Words) where I sort by the longest word first and then assign a category in (column K)

Next I want to match (column I in All Words -> (search term correctly sorted by length) with words in the the Lookup tab -> category match.

Once the longest word is found, it must be deleted so that it cannot be found by another variant again.

How can I make the result look like "Result must be" in the Lookup tab??

I made a test Google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fd22ho_1KNaGIu2tyfmO6AkhpyJqu58aIdYExyLSZCM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/INhCh.png

Comment: It's pretty close to the goal, but with this formula I only find the first word / phrase in the search string [category]christmas tree[category].

But how do I find the next word also, in this case december, so the result will be [category]christmas tree[category] [month]december[month] ?

Comment: This formular only find the first word / phrase in the search string:  

How do I love thee?  
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;TEXTJOIN("|";1;'All Words'!A2:A));'All Words'!H2:K;4;0)))  
How can I find the next word in the phrase?

Comment: This one works but finds only the first word  
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;TEXTJOIN("|";1;'All Words'!A2:A));'All Words'!H2:K;4;0)))  
Can the formula be set to search for more words?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A; 
 TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; 'All Words'!A2:A)); 'All Words'!A2:D; 4; 0))&" "&IFNA(
 VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A; IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;
 TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; 'All Words'!A2:A))); "")); 
 TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; 'All Words'!A2:A)); 'All Words'!A2:D; 4; 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice, now it finds one more word.  
I need to have the longest word (most characters) written first, such that:  
[category]christmas tree[category] [month]december[month]
[month]december[month] [category]christmas tree[category]  

Must be:
[category]christmas tree[category] [month]december[month]
[category]christmas tree[category] [month]december[month]  

Is it possible?

Comment: Help here anyone?

Comment: 1) Instead of looking up 2 search term, can I look up 3 search term too?
2) I need to write the longest search term (most characters) first also